# role of parentheses in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know the difference between the following and the role of the parentheses:

```
foo.bar.replace(a,b)
```

and

```
(foo.bar).replace(a,b)
```

do the parentheses require the contained expression to be evaluated first before moving on to the replace method? I have seen this in code I am maintaining and am curious as to why it would be neccessary? E.G.

```
location.hash.replace(a,b)
```

and

```
(location.hash).replace(a,b)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not required in your examples.

The idea is indeed that the block inside the parenthesis must be evaluated before continuing..

It is needed in cases like

```
(new Date()).getMilliseconds()
```

(*not really needed in this case as noted by @Teemu*)

---

In general use this syntax to avoid using a temporary variable..

```
var result = 5.3 + 2.9;
console.log( result.toFixed(1) );
```

can become

```
console.log( (5.3 +2.9).toFixed(1) );
```

If you were to use `5.3 + 2.9.toFixed(1)` the `toFixed(1)` would get applied to 2.9 only, return a string and then concatenate it with 5.3 The result would be ***5.32.9***

Comment: i'd like to know examples of when it is required

Comment: @njorlsaga when grouping something that you want to occur before the next part, like calculations... `(5 + 3).toString()`

Comment: @Gaby thanks for your answer, I follow the need for the parentheses with calculations before calling the toFixed method. In my examples `foo.bar.replace(a,b)` foo.bar needs to evaluate to a string. So could I assume that wherever you use a temporary variable and assign it foo of some type and then perform bar method, as long as foo is of the right type I would not need the temporay variable? E.G. 
`var foo = object.prop //prop is a string;  
foo.bar();`  
or  
`var foo =object.prop //prop is a function
foo().bar(); // = object.prop().bar()`

Comment: @njorlsaga, 1st. bar in your example (*`foo.bar.replace(a,b)`*) is not a method but a property so you cannot *perform* it. In your later examples, assigning a method of an object to a variable it changes its context. When you do `ar foo =object.prop //prop is a function` then `foo()` is called on the window context and not on the `object` context, and this means that if the original `prop()` method tried to access other properties of `object` through `this` it would now not find them.. See example at ***http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/pSLax/***