# Why does the pointing of `this` not change

Tags: javascript

```js
let o = {
  a: 123,
  b: function () {
    console.log(this, this.a);
  },
};

(o.b)()
```

Like this code, my understanding is that the code is like this:

```js
const b = o.b
b() // this is pointing to window
```

But for `(o.b)()`, `this` keyword is pointing the o object, why is that?

Comment: This might help, no pun intended: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp

Comment: Related, though they didn't specifically talk about the `this`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320835/role-of-parentheses-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Putting parentheses around an object reference to a function will only change the `this` from the object if there's *something else* inside the parentheses that makes the interpreter first resolve the value inside the parentheses to something else first (for example, if you use any of the operators, or invoke a function inside the parentheses).

```js
let o = {
  a: 123,
  b: function () {
    console.log(this === window);
  },
};

// Using comma operator now
(0, o.b)()
```

But if all you have is a plain method reference on an object, with nothing else inside the parentheses, the calling context doesn't change - the extra parentheses around the reference doesn't change it.

Comment: Buy why, this is the first time I realized this problem.